# Create App or Create a Custom ROM?

Tags: java, android, rom, kiosk-mode

I have a client who is interested in developing a kiosk for him. He is using a particular tablet device where he wants to use the Android ICS as the operating system to control the hardware of the device.

Now he wants an app developed on top of it which will work as the **mother app**.

The feature of this mother app is it will lock out all the other features available to user. As I know it is possible to develop such an app.

Now the problem I'm facing is his next requirement.

The client wants this mother app to control the installation of apps on the device and these apps will be installed as the child apps of this mother app. According to his requirements he wants this mother app to control the life cycle of the child apps.

Now I couldn't find any solution to do this from an app (My bad!). So I thought of the option to change the Application Framework of the Android itself to meet this requirement (possibly creating a custom ROM).

What do you suggest? Is there any way to do this from an app itself or do I have to modify the Application Framework for it.

Comment: Simply put, you can't do it from a "mother app" for sure. There's no access to control other apps' lifecycle events. A custom ROM *might* work, but it's most likely going to take some heavy modifications. If you haven't already, you might want to explain why his "requirements" don't make much sense. There are other ways to run a kiosk mode.

Comment: Well you can take a look at the task killers. Some of them allow you to control which apps will open and which don't. Sure as hell you can't modify the life cycle of the activities but you can control it, telling which apps should be closed (prior configurating the app and selecting some banned processes)

Comment: Will look into your solutions and try to figure out a way. Thanks!

Comment: What kind of lifecycle control do you want, exactly? There's a lot you can do with root.

Comment: Why would you (or your client) want one app to control another? This seems a very PC-area concept, and is mostly unnecessary on Android - the OS controls the app's life cycle just about right, including background processing to download new versions. As for kiosk mode, checkout the [screen pinning API](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html)